# Access to base class function

Tags: c++, inheritance

```
class Base
{
    public: void foo(){}
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    private:
    using Base::foo;
};

int main()
{
   Derived d;
   d.foo();
}
```

Is the code legal? The declaration `using Base::foo` is in the private section of the derived class. So the call `d.foo()` shouldn't compile, am I right?

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: You have accepted @Prasoon Saurav's answer, which is fine.  But you need to be aware that this method, while technically legal, is deprecated and should not be used in green-field development.

Comment: Moreover, the defect link provided by @Prasoon Saurav basically seems to say "yes this is what the standard says, but that's not what we intended it to say."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Standard in section 11.2/4 says

> A member m is accessible when named in class N if
>
> —  m as a member of N is public, or
>
> —  m as a member of N is private, and the reference occurs in a member or friend of class N, or
>
> —  m as a member of N is protected, and the reference occurs in a member or friend  of  class N,  or  in  a
>   member or friend of a class P derived from N, where m as a member of P is private or protected, or
>
> —  **there exists a base class B of N that is accessible at the point of reference, and m is accessible when named in class B**.

However the Standard also says that

> §11.3/1 "The access of a member of a base class can be changed in the derived class.

In your code the access of the member `foo` has been changed in the derived class. So the code shouldn't compile but [**this is still an active issue with open status**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#360)  So some compilers compile the code (Comeau and Intel C++) whereas g++ and MSVC++ (correctly) reject it.

Comment: I swear you must have the standard memorized ;)  The reference is always appreciated.

Comment: -1 g++ and msvc disagree. and so does the Holy Standard (@prasoon, I really hate it when people bring up quoted from the HS that seemingly contradict what I've already written! <g>). if you had just read on to the next para in the HS, namely §11.3, it's entirely devoted to *access declarations*, "The access of a member of a base class can be changed in a derived class ... the effect is defined to be equivalent to the declaration using `using` *qualified-id*". Such access declarations were the old pre-strandard way. `using` is the C98 way. cheers & hth.,

Comment: @Prasoon: formally, wrt. the quoted text from the standard, I think it hinges on "when named in class B". Earlier in this very same paragraph, which you didn't quote, you find "The access to a member is affected by the class in which the member is named. This naming class is the class in which the member name was looked up and found". In the OP's example there is a declaration of the name in class `Derived`. So as I see it that's where it's named. Thus the qualification in the last bullet point excludes that bullet point. Cheers & hth.,

Comment: @Prasoon Saurav:  the statement that "`d.foo()` is fine" is incorrect.  The access is modified to private by means of the `using` declaration.  Please edit your response.

Comment: That section of the standard looks like it has all sorts of defects.  AFAICT the third bullet is flat-out wrong.  It's not sufficient that the access occur in a class `P` derived from `N`, but the target of the member-reference operator has to have type `P` as well.

Comment: @Alf: I think you're misreading the clause.  "when named in class `B`" means "if it were qualified by class `B`", not "it is being named in class `B`".  After all, we are told specifically that `m` is "named in class N".

Comment: @Ben: I agree that there is a contradiction in the wording (thanks, I didn't see that earlier!). However, the example that's attached to bullet point 4 makes clear what it's all about: a name that is looked up in a base class, and that isn't present in derived class. And apart from that concrete example illustrating the intention, the bullet point doesn't make sense (is inconsistent with rest of standard such as §7.3.3/13  and §11.3) with your interpretation. Cheers & hth.,

Comment: @Alf: Oh I agree that bullet point 4 is intended to apply to names that aren't present in the derived class, and it really ought just to say that.  e.g. `class N` has no member `m` and there exists a base class `B` of `N`...

Comment: And the other sentence from the standard "the access specifier can be changed" could grammatically mean "but only to make it MORE accessible".  I don't think this is the intent, I think the intent is that the base class member not be accessible using an unqualified name, just as if the derived class had defined a new private member of the same name, but it certainly is accessible by adding an upcast, so in that sense, the derived class CANNOT make the access specifier more restrictive.

Comment: I discused this too in the past with a clang developer: http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=8178

Comment: @Ben third bullet is restricted to what you say by 11.5

Answer (score 5):

Right.

Now reality check…

MinGW g++ 4.4.1:

> x.cpp: In function 'int main()':
>   x.cpp:3: error: 'void Base::foo()' is
>   inaccessible
>   x.cpp:15: error: within
>   this context

Visual C++ 10.0:

> x.cpp(15) : error C2248:
>   'Derived::foo' : cannot access private
>   member declared in class 'Derived'
>           x.cpp(9) : see declaration of 'Derived::foo'
>           x.cpp(6) : see declaration of 'Derived'

[Comeau Online](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout/) 4.3.10.1:

> In strict mode, with -tused, Compile
>   succeeded (but remember, the Comeau
>   online compiler does not link).
>   Compiled with C++0x extensions
>   enabled.

*Oops*. And Comeau is the one that's nearly always right! Well, turning off C++0x extensions, for C++98/C++03:

> In strict mode, with -tused, Compile
>   succeeded (but remember, the Comeau
>   online compiler does not link).
>   Compiled with C++0x extensions
>   DISabled.

**Oops!**

Well, you biggie mine, as they say in Norway (literally translated to English).

I'd try to report that to Comeau.

**EDIT**: since Prasoon has also answered, quoting the Holy Standard with his interpretation of that contradicting what I wrote above, well, OK, standadeese…

§11.3/1 "The access of a member of a base class can be changed in the derived class…", and so on, which is as clear as can be (no interpretation required). And with a concrete example. And normative text stating that that is equivalent to a `using` declaration.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: is this a bug in comeau or in g++?

Comment: @Alf, please see 7.3.3/15 for a concrete example that *does* adjust access specifiers with the using declaration.  Are there two ways to do this, or is the standard ambigious (wouldnt be the first time or even the 1000th time), or is one of our interpretations incorrect?

Comment: @John: (1) no that example doesn't adjust access (it's an example of trying to access something that is inaccessible); (2) yes, there are two ways (one pre-standard and deprecated, and the C++98 `using`); and (3) like Prasoon you should have read on, to the next paragraph, in your case §7.3.3/16 -- even though it's just non-normative note. Cheers & hth.,

Comment: @Alf: Hehe! Found something [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#360) :)

Comment: @Alf:  deprecated doesn't mean invalid.  OP simply asked "does this work" and by my reading the answer is "yes."  Well, maybe a better answer is "yes, but you should do it this other way"

Comment: @John: right, deprecated doesn't mean invalid. and right, the answer is "yes". and no, it's not better to do it the deprecated way, if that's what you mean. Cheers & hth.,

Comment: @Alf:  That is what I mean.  OP's question was simply "does this work?" and the answer is "yes."  Maybe a better answer would be "yes, but you shouldn't do it this way," but @Prasoon Saurav's answer is correct, and I don't think shoud be downvoted.

Comment: @John: we seem agree on everything except Prasoon's answer. That answer is incorrect. The formal is very simple, and apart from that, the in-practice is and has always been as I say (except for Comeau). Essentially it boils down to where the name is looked up, and the unquoted part of Prasoon's paragraph goes to pains to define that. That's why the quoted part has a *qualification*.

Comment: @John: update: no we don't agree on everything. you misquoted the OP's question. The question is, "am I right?". The answer is "yes, it should not compile". AFAIK the only compiler accepting it is Comeau.

Comment: @Alf : The code also gets compiled on Intel C++ apart from Comeau. :-)

Comment: @Alf:  You're right.  When I saw "Is this code legal" I mistankenly interpreted it as "Can I change access specifiers in this way"  I agree that 1) Technically you can change access specifiers in this way, 2) You should not change access specifiers this way, 3) The code should not compile because `d.foo()` is trying to access a `private`

Comment: @Alf:  Are we squared away on this?

Comment: @John: yes, on the points you list. I don't follow the (earlier?) conclusion that Prasoon's answer is correct, since Prasoon writes "The code should compile" while you write  --  which I agree with  -- "The code should not compile". Cheers,

Comment: Just more info, part 1: C++98 standard differs from ARM: I checked TCPPPL 2nd edition and the ARM (they're from the same time, pre-standard, respectively 1991 and 1990), and they both say "An access declaration may not be used to restrict access to a member that is accessible in the base class", and additionally restricts access declarations to protected and public. In the C++98 standard, however, §7.3.3 and §11.3, this language has been *removed*.

Comment: Just more info, part 2: §7.3.3/13 states "For the purpose of overload resolution, the functions which are introduced by a *using-declaration* into a derived class will be treated as though they were members of the derived class." This certainly applies to the OP's code. And as a member of the derived class, `foo` is inaccessible.

Comment: @Prasoon: That Intel and Comeau agree shouldn't be surprising, since they both use EDG's compiler frontend.

Comment: And for those who read this later, please note that also I was confused, when writing first above that "has always been", then finding contrary wording in the ARM and CPPPL 2nd ed (language removed in the standard).

Comment: @Alf : Completely revised/edited the post. Have a look and please tell me whether it is correct or not.

Comment: @Prasoon: have a look at §7.3.3/13 "For the purpose of overload resolution, the functions which are introduced by a using-declaration into a derived class will be treated as though they were members of the derived class." That's the OP's `foo`. As a member of `Derived` it is inaccessible. Your new wording implies a contradiction with §11.2/4. But there is no contradiction. Cheers,

Comment: I discused this too in the past with a clang developer: http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=8178 and I disagree with your (and with that guy's) interpretation, but people certainly have different opinion on this.

Comment: However I think I'm starting to change my opinion on this. While it's true that the final name lookup result will refer only to `Base::foo`, and that member name is public when named in class `Base`, this doesn't apply to all intermediary names used by name lookup that established this binding (see also 11/4). In particulary, when encountering the using declaration, we need to check that declaration's member name accessibility too. And then it applies what John McCall said: In the base class, there doesn't exist such a member name.

Answer (score 0):

`using` is a namespace declaration in this example (as opposed to a namespace *directive*). It is not a method declaration, as you seem to be intending to use it as.

The method `foo()` is public in the `Base` class, and is still accessible in the `Derived` class.

You seem to be intending to make the `foo()` of the `Base` class inaccessible. Although there might be a way to do this (I wouldn't know, I've never had a reason to attempt it), I suggest that this points out an error with the logic of your inheritance, and you may want to consider redesigning y our classes.

If your `Derived` class isn't going to behave as a `Base` class, it shouldn't inherit from a `Base` class.

Comment: -1 using the using declaration in this way makes `foo` inaccessible through `Derived`

Comment: @John Dibling: Thank you for the -1. If you wanted to give a better explanation, feel free so that future readers might understand better. But so far your stated reason is "`foo` is inaccessible" while the OP, the accepted answer, *and* your other comments say exactly the opposite. If the first sentence of my answer is incorrect, add something of value and explain why. Truth is, I don't have the standard memorized, but I tried my best to be helpful based on my understanding of the usage. Correct me if I'm wrong, sure, but don't just contradict yourself and take a stab at my rep.

Comment: @KevenK:  The -1 was not personal, and it was not a "stab" at your rep.    We are supposed to upvote correct responses & downvote incorrect responses.  Your statement "The method foo() [...] is still accessible in the Derived class." is factually incorrect.  It this were a secondary point, I wouldn't care.  But it was a direct response to the OP's fundamental question.  Don't take it personal -- I get d/v's all the time, and I see them as an opportunity to learn something I didn't know.

Comment: @KevenK:  In addition, I commented exactly why I d/v'ed.  I do this whenever I d/v precisely so readers may understand better.  I even removed it when I thought I might be incorrect in my conclusions.  Both of these are far more courteous than you'll get from a lot of people on SO.  If you think my reason for the d/v was wrong, let me know.  I'm always willing to discuss it.  And when I'm shown to be wrong, either in posts or in d/v's, I own up to it.

Comment: @Keven: I'm not sure what you're complaining about. You posted an answer that had been incorrect in its very first sentence and also in the conclusions drawn from there. That answer got down-voted for being incorrect. John even held back down-voting because he wasn't sure whether you haven't arrived to the right conclusion starting from wrong premises, which I consider unnecessary, since the first sentence is worth a down-vote all by itself. So stop complaining and be glad you had the chance to learn a meaning of `using` you didn't know about.

Comment: @John Dibling: I fully understand and in fact *do* appreciate the mention of the d/v. Likewise, I too seek only to have corrections where possible so that the right information can be passed to future readers. I don't have a problem with this system, nor do I have a personal problem (or did I take personal offense). In fact, I am specifically asking for corrections here. But here you said the d/v was because "`foo` is inaccessible through `Derived`", but in the Accepted answer it is stated that "`d.foo()` is fine", which you stated was correct. This appears as a contradiction to me.

Comment: @sbi: You seem to think that I'm complaining like a 3rd grader who found out someone didn't like me. You may not have noticed that even *I* specifically noted that my first sentence appears to be wrong, as I did not know the depth of `using` in the standard. Since the beginning, I have simply wanted to come to the right answer and understand what was wrong. The answer stated so far appears to be contradictory to other responses on this page, so I question. I learn by asking questions...if that looks like complaining to you, I suggest new glasses. 2 rep isn't a big deal, confusing answers are.

Comment: Also, I'm done with this question. It is absolutely true that I did not know the depth of `using` and that my answer is wrong. No question there. Further discussion here doesn't appear to be helpful though, so I will move on. I'd consider just deleting this answer as neither it nor the comments that follow are helpful to the OP or future readers, but I don't want to appear to be "embarrassed" or anything of the sort. /shrug

Comment: @KevenK:  Two things.  First, sorry if I misinterpreted your tone.  I concluded this based on the general tone of your comment.  "stab at my rep" seemed to be snotty, so if it wasn't, then I apologize for my misinterpretation.

Comment: Second:  You're absolutely right that @Prasoon Saurav's post is factually incorrect in the statement that `d.foo()` is fine.  It's not fine, and @Prasoon Saurav should edit the response.  The confusion is partly my fault, which I realized in the C++ chat room, when I interpreted the OP's question "Is the code legal?" as "can I change access specifiers this way?"  Some of my comments were not precise, and this caused confusion.

Comment: Also componded by the fact that I completely misunderstood @Prasoon Saurav's response to mean "yes this changes access" when it fact it says "no this doesnt change access and should compile."  Thanks, @KevenK for pointing this out.

Comment: @KevenK actually you appear more "embarassed" if you *don't* delete the answer.

Comment: @Johannes Schaub - litb: I do not see the relevance or helpfulness of your comment. If you have an intent here aside from "trolling", I'm afraid it's lost on me.